# Reinforced learning agent build DQNAgent causes unknown problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, openai-gym

I wanted to get into reinforced learning a bit, so I started with the fairly simple example "Cartpole" by following a hands-on tutorial.
[Github link of the tutorial source code (identical with mine)](https://github.com/nicknochnack/TensorflowKeras-ReinforcementLearning)
Unfortunately I've been stuck with the same error for two days and can't find a simliar problem/ solution based on the TypeError. The Error message says the following:

*File "C:\Users\Felix\Dropbox\Pendelcart.py", line 40, in dqn = build_agent(model, actions)

File "C:\Users\Felix\Dropbox\Pendelcart.py", line 29, in build_agent dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory, policy=policy, nb_actions =actions,

File "C:\Users\Felix\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\rl\agents\dqn.py", line 108, in init if hasattr(model.output, 'len') and len(model.output) > 1:

File "C:\Users\Felix\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\keras_tensor.py", line 240, in len raise TypeError('Keras symbolic inputs/outputs do not '

TypeError: Keras symbolic inputs/outputs do not implement **len**. You may be trying to pass Keras symbolic inputs/outputs to a TF API that does not register dispatching, preventing Keras from automatically converting the API call to a lambda layer in the Functional Model. This error will also get raised if you try asserting a symbolic input/output directly.*

I genuinely hope someone here can help me out. I work with Pyhton 3.8, Tensorflow 2.4.0 and Keras 2.4.3. The complete sourcecode is attached bellow.

Thank you in advance and happy holidays.

```
import gym
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from rl.agents import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import BoltzmannQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory


def build_model(states, actions):
    model = Sequential()
    # model.add(Input(shape=(1,states)))
    model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1,states)))
    model.add(Dense(24,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(24,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(actions,activation='linear'))
    return model

def build_agent(model,actions):
    policy = BoltzmannQPolicy()
    memory = SequentialMemory(limit = 50000, window_length=1)
    dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory, policy=policy, nb_actions =actions,
                   nb_steps_warmup=10, target_model_update=1e-2)
    return dqn

env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
states = env.observation_space.shape[0]
actions = env.action_space.n

model = build_model(states, actions)
model.summary()

dqn = build_agent(model, actions)
dqn.compile(Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])
dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=50000, visualize= False, verbose=1)
```

Comment: What is the rl library which has dqnagent? And can you add your full error traceback

Comment: Thanks for the quick reponse. I think the rl librbary is the keras-rl2 library. I've added the full traceback to the original post

Comment: I think you may have the wrong library of `keras-rl` installed. You need `keras-rl2` and not `keras-rl`. uninstall `keras-rl` and install `keras-rl2`.

Comment: I have actually both of them installed, keras-rl (0.4.2) and keras-rl2(1.0.4). Could that cause the conflict?

Comment: Yes. Your error is coming from the keras-rl library.

Comment: That acutally resolved the problem, thanks a lot